# Would it possible to send Chinese Language in Exact Target SMS API?

Tags: marketing-cloud, sms

Would it possible to send Chinese Language in **Exact Target SMS API**?

Comment: Yes, but are you wanting to send to mainland China? If  so, the API wouldn't be your limitation.

Comment: No problem. You're welcome.

Comment: Thank you. can you please share me some reference documents.

Comment: sending SMS in Chinese. i got success response from server. but SMS is not delivered.  Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: Which country are you sending to?

Answer (score 1):

Marketing Cloud doesn't let you send SMS to mainland China. To do this, you would have to use a 3rd party provider ( like Piery or Twillio) or create a custom activity on Journey builder.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for options on a system to send SMS messages in mainland China, some you could consider are:

- http://www.c123.cn
- http://www.boshitonginfo.com/duanxinfuwu.html

(I'm not affiliated with them, but I have used their service before)

I've also heard good things about the following, although I haven't personally used them before:

- https://cloud.tencent.com/document/product/382/3784
- http://www.monyun.cn/portalpage/ser_msgVerf.html

Answer (score 0):

With regard to the character set, yes, you can use the Chinese characters.  However, there is one limitation.  While SMS messages sent in English are limited to 140 characters per charged message, Chinese SMS messages are limited to 70 characters per charged message.

In this example, if you have message with 240 Chinese characters, you would be charged for 4 SMS messages ( 3 * 70 + 1 * 30 = 240).  Where as in English, you would only be charged for two SMS messages for 240 characters ( 1 * 140 + 1 * 100 = 240).